# No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it

Tags: ssh, display, java, xorg

I am trying to install a program on RedHAt7 using ssh / connecting to server.  I received the output the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.greenstone.gatherer.Gatherer.init(Gatherer.java:284)
    at org.greenstone.gatherer.Gatherer.<init>(Gatherer.java:234)
    at org.greenstone.gatherer.GathererProg.main(GathererProg.java:78)

Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException:
    No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.greenstone.gatherer.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:111)
    ... 3 more
```

How to fix X11 Display?

Answer (score 1):

If X server is running on the target host and you want the program to display there, you usually perform 'export DISPLAY=:0' where :0 would mean the first X server running. If you are running several X servers (for example Xvnc) on the target host, :0 may become :1 or another number, depending on X server configuration.

If you have X server running locally (the machine you are connecting from) you could use 'ssh -X ...' or 'ssh -Y' to log in to the host and forward your display to the program run remotely. See other [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely) on redirecting X server over SSH.

Edit: Please check the answer in the linked article.
**TL;DR:**

1. Ensure xauth is installed on target
2. In /etc/sshd_config set `X11Forwarding yes`
3. Run ssh with -vv to check what is the problem, if any

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkCentre-M58p ~ $ ssh -Y root@server ip address...
root server ip...'s password:
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0.
why happened like this

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkCentre-M58p ~ $ ssh -X root@server ip address...
root server ip...'s password:
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0.

Comment: both tried X and Y

Comment: ssh -X -1  not works